# how to store list of numbers to database

Tags: database, database-design

Hi I'm trying to store group, subgroup, and user information in a database (SQLite). A group can have multiple subgroup, and user can belong to multiple groups/subgroups as following.

- Group 1 has subgroup a,b,c and user A,B.
- Group 2 has subgroup d,e and user B,C,D.
- subgroup d has user B,D and belongs to group 2.
- user B belongs to Group 1,2 and subgroup a,c,d.

It should be able to searched by group, subgroup or user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following table structure makes the following assumptions:

1. Subgroups are unique and distinct to each group, and are distinct from actual Groups (one-to many relationship, and Groups are not useable as subgroups).
2. Users must be members of at least one subgroup in order to participate in a group

   GroupTable
       GroupID (PK)
       GroupName

   SubGroupTable
       SubGroupID (PK)
       GroupID (FK on GroupTable.GroupID)
       SubGroupName

   UserTable
       UserID (PK)
       UserName

Now, create a many-to-many relation table establishing User participation within one or more sub-groups:

```
User_Sub_Groups
    UserID (FK on UserTable.UserID)
    SubGroupID (FK on SubGroupTable.SubGroupID)
```

If Groups are also able to be subgroups, then the example provided by nulvinge is one option, though I would do it slightly differently:

```
GroupTable
    GroupID (PK)
    GroupName

UserTable
    UserID (PK)
    UserName

SubGroupTable
    ParentGroupID (Composite Key on GroupsTable.GroupID)
    SubGroupID (Composite Key on GroupsTable.GroupID)

UserGroupsTable
    UserID (Composite Key on UserTable.UserID)
    GroupID (Composite Key on GroupsTable.GroupID)
```

From here, you simply use the JOIN between various tables to perform your search. For example, to return all Users who belong to a certain Group:

```
SELECT     
    tblUser_Group.GroupID, tblUser.*
FROM         
    tblUser_Group 
INNER JOIN  
    tblUser ON tblUser_Group.UserID = tblUser.UserID
WHERE 
    tblUserGroup.GroupID = @GroupID
```

To return all SubGroups of which a specific User is a member:

```
SELECT    
    tblGroup.GroupName AS SubGroupName
FROM         
    tblUser_Group AS UG 
INNER JOIN
    tblUser ON UG.UserID = tblUser.UserID INNER JOIN
    tblGroup_SubGroup AS GSG ON UG.GroupID = GSG.SubGroupID INNER JOIN
    tblGroup ON GSG.SubGroupID = tblGroup.GroupID
WHERE     
    tblUser.UserID = 1
```

And so on. It can be challenging to think your way through the various JOIN permutations at first, but this is a very flexible and scaleable arrangement.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
Group:
  id
  NULL overgroup_id

Membership:
  user_id
  group_id    

User:
  id
```

A group that has overgroup_id = NULL is a group, otherwise it's a subgroup.

To find all users_ids in a group with id gid, with subgroups:

```
select user_id
from Membership
where group_id=gid
or group_id in
    (select group.id from Group where overgoup_id=gid)
```